# Place JButton in defined position

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a problem, i searched on many topics how to place a JButton on a JPanel with a defined position. The most current answer i found is that, i should display layout of JFrame and set it to null, so here is my code. But the thing is that when i'm setting layout to null nothing works anymore.

```
package loto;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Accueil extends JFrame{
    public Accueil(){
        this.setTitle("Accueil du loto");
        this.setSize(1920,1080);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fond pan = new fond();
        JButton suivant = new JButton("Commencer le Loto");
        pan.setLayout(null);
        pan.add(suivant);
        suivant.setBounds(1800, 400, 40, 300);
        this.setContentPane(pan);

        while (true) {
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats because you set layout to null. don't do it. the layoutmanager will do the layout for you. easy one is BorderLayout

Comment: Have a look at [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Plus this code has no business being there: `while (true) { this.repaint();}` as it has potential to freeze your GUI rendering it useless.

Comment: *"..when i'm setting layout to null nothing works anymore."* Yep. That's one of the reasons that no experienced developer would recommend them to a newbie. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. BTW - `this.setSize(1920,1080);` that sounds suspiciously close to 'full screen' on a number of desktop computer set ups. If that is the aim, I'd recommend [`setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-)..

Comment: I maybe don't know how to do it but if set the Layout to Border my button will be placed at center or in cardinals. I havn't found a way to set a JButton in desired coordonates with the BorderrLayout.
Yeah this is the aim to be in fullscreen. Thanks i will try it asap

Answer (score 0):

When you are new to Swing, you have to go by step by step UI,

> 1. Ensure the JPanel is added to your JFrame...  fond pan = new fond(); Is it a JPanel subclass? you dont need to do this way you can
>      create JPanel jp = new JPanel();
> 2. add this JPanel component to JFrame by calling this.add(jp) in your constructor.
> 3. three important properties for every Swing display is  a) setVisible   b)setLayout  c)setContentPane  d) add
> 4. You have added JButton to Jpanel but you have not added Jpanel to JFrame.

add properties this.add(pan), this.setLayout(new FlowLayout()) in your constructor.

remove the while loop from your constructor.

Comment: Does the FlowLayout permit me to place the JButton anywhere i want ?

Comment: Nope. FlowLayout usually places the components from Left to Right order. For testing I have used FlowLayout. Once components are shown for FlowLayout you have to Change setLayout(null) & setBounds(x,y,width,height) to fix the component in a particular position

Comment: I keeped the null layout but it works now :) Thanks. I just added

    this.add(pan);

before the pan.add(JButton);

Answer (score 0):

Using null-Layout, you have to set a size and a location for your JButton like this:

```
suivant.setSize(120,20);
suivant.setLocation(x,y);
```